# Audio player in UITableViewCell reset when hidden

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which I have different types of cell. One of them is an AVPlayer. Another is a YouTube video.

**EDIT** : The problem is that when I scroll to hide the cell and then scroll back to display it, my player gets reset.

I understand why, but I would like to know how to avoid it and keep my music playing.

I've tried to create properties, strong :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) DWPlayerCellVC *playerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DWVideoCellVC *videoView;
```

and have :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"player"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"player"];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        NSArray *viewsToRemove = [cell.contentView subviews];
        for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }

        self.playerView = [[DWPlayerCellVC alloc] init];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.playerView.view];
```

but it doesn't work...

Any ideas ? :/

Comment: `if(!self.playerView){self.playerView = [[DWPlayerCellVC alloc] init];}` try this!

Comment: I've edited my post: The cell gets reset when I display it again, and not when it gets hidden.

Comment: I've tried with adding the condition,  if(!self.playerView){
            
            self.playerView = [[DWPlayerCellVC alloc] init];
            
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.playerView.view];                         self.playerView.model = self.model[indexPath.row];
        }  and it does help ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your player on table scrollview with position frame equal with that cell in tableview and then the player will not be erased with cell... but will remain on the scroll...